PDF to CSV in as400
I am trying to convert a PDF report into CSV file.
So currently a query is used to generate the report. To convert into csv, i wrote a CL program and added two commands

RUNQRY and saved the output in a pf in my library
CPYTOIMPF to copy the pf as csv into ifs folder.

When I do a wrknlk and check the folder, I can see proper data but when I download the file in Access Client solutions, I see junk values.

it seems you have not defined ccsid code. If it is the case, read options from CPYTOIMPF in order to create a csv with the desired target ccsid (a ccsid according to your csv requirements). Probably, if you did not defined target ccsid, it defaulted to an ebcdic character set.

Charles points also to ccsid system value. It happens in a lot of cases that system value continues being defined as 65535.

Thank you. Your solution worked. CCSID i used is 1252.

thanks you for notifying...CCSID is a matter to be learned very well. IBM made a great work on globalization of all aspects of interchanges among differents environments. If you work in an international ecosystem, you should read about IBM globalization items
